# Get Tweet ID from output?

Tags: php, twitter

I am posting a tweet with a picture, and I am trying to get the ID from it. I have asked it before, but for some reason it's not working anymore? Here is my code:

```
require 'tmhOAuth.php';
require 'tmhUtilities.php';

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '****',
    'consumer_secret' => '****',
    'user_token' => '****',
    'user_secret' => '****',
)); 

$image = "./../images/image.png";

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
    'status'   => "Don't slip up" 
),
true,
true 
);

print_r($tmhOAuth);

$tweet_id = $tmhOAuth->id_str;

echo "<br><br><br> Try this: $tweet_id";
```

I get a whole bunch of text from the `print_r`, but `$tweet_id` is blank? I know it's in there. Here's part of the output:

```
"id_str":"104032165678944257"
```

Here's the full response:

```
tmhOAuth Object ( [params] => Array ( ) [headers] => Array ( [Authorization] => OAuth oauth_consumer_key="nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ", oauth_nonce="dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9", oauth_signature="lHjemKp%2BJVmVgD3cQ9ady4Qb66o%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1313638299", oauth_token="129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll", oauth_version="1.0" [Expect] => ) [auto_fixed_time] => [buffer] => [config] => Array ( [consumer_key] => nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ [consumer_secret] => 64UGkGOcwqAKSLieXHOVBFgkXFJujYFkhzYTd1Yjls [user_token] => 129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll [user_secret] => udoKo0bRmNcKY9WIHEi8cWDMldPS5PyGYEgrYWRcWPk [use_ssl] => 1 [host] => upload.twitter.com [debug] => [force_nonce] => [nonce] => dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9 [force_timestamp] => [timestamp] => 1313638299 [oauth_version] => 1.0 [curl_connecttimeout] => 30 [curl_timeout] => 10 [curl_ssl_verifypeer] => [curl_followlocation] => [curl_proxy] => [curl_proxyuserpwd] => [is_streaming] => [streaming_eol] => [streaming_metrics_interval] => 60 [as_header] => 1 [multipart] => 1 ) [method] => POST [url] => https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json [request_params] => Array ( [media[]] => @./../images/appstore_icon.png [status] => Don't slip up ) [signing_params] => oauth_consumer_key=nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ&oauth_nonce=dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1313638299&oauth_token=129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll&oauth_version=1.0 [auth_params] => Array ( [oauth_consumer_key] => nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ [oauth_nonce] => dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9 [oauth_signature] => lHjemKp%2BJVmVgD3cQ9ady4Qb66o%3D [oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1 [oauth_timestamp] => 1313638299 [oauth_token] => 129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll [oauth_version] => 1.0 ) [base_string] => POST&https%3A%2F%2Fupload.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate_with_media.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DnY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ%26oauth_nonce%3Ddfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1313638299%26oauth_token%3D129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll%26oauth_version%3D1.0 [signing_key] => 64UGkGOcwqAKSLieXHOVBFgkXFJujYFkhzYTd1Yjls&udoKo0bRmNcKY9WIHEi8cWDMldPS5PyGYEgrYWRcWPk [auth_header] => OAuth oauth_consumer_key="nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ", oauth_nonce="dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9", oauth_signature="lHjemKp%2BJVmVgD3cQ9ady4Qb66o%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1313638299", oauth_token="129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll", oauth_version="1.0" [response] => Array ( [headers] => Array ( [date] => Thu, 18 Aug 2011 03:29:36 GMT [server] => hi [status] => 200 OK [x_transaction] => 1313638175-75577-25147 [x_mediaratelimit_remaining] => 12 [x_mediaratelimit_class] => photos [etag] => "e8f1edd9abbb4ba6c9b92464ec4e2847" [last_modified] => Thu, 18 Aug 2011 03:29:35 GMT [x_frame_options] => SAMEORIGIN [x_mediaratelimit_limit] => 30 [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [x_transaction_mask] => a6183ffa5f8ca943ff1b53b5644ef114b7a0cbbd [x_runtime] => 0.51368 [pragma] => no-cache [content_length] => 2580 [x_access_level] => read-write [x_mediaratelimit_reset] => 1313722601 [cache_control] => no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0 [expires] => Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT [x_revision] => DEV [x_mid] => 38cf611ea13ba444edf613338dacef6a5cb496e3 [set_cookie] => _twitter_sess=BAh7CjoMY3NyZl9pZCIlOWE2YjA3NWMyZTJiZTliZjllZmI4MzkwYzQxYTdh%250AZDM6D2NyZWF0ZWRfYXRsKwgK1O%252FaMQE6B3VhIh90aGVtYXR0aGFycmlzJyBI%250AVFRQIENsaWVudDoHaWQiJTZkZDc1MjNkZjQ1NTlhZjMwODVlMzQ3M2NjNjg5%250AY2FlIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVyOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hI%250AYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--0657ee6f8e05f42d4eb8ec769f4b445348bbee9c; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly [vary] => Accept-Encoding [connection] => close ) [code] => 200 [response] => {"text":"Don't slip up http:\/\/t.co\/lt5DjR6","id_str":"104032165674749952","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"created_at":"Thu Aug 18 03:29:36 +0000 2011","entities":{"hashtags":[],"media":[{"type":"photo","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/lt5DjR6","media_url":"http:\/\/p.twimg.com\/AXGYtBiCEAEmcBL.png","indices":[14,33],"id_str":"104032165678944257","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/yourwaywebsites\/status\/104032165674749952\/photo\/1","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/lt5DjR6","media_url_https":"https:\/\/p.twimg.com\/AXGYtBiCEAEmcBL.png","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":1018,"h":331,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":1018,"h":331,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1018,"h":331,"resize":"fit"}},"id":104032165678944257}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"source":"\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/myflashpics.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003EFlashPics\u003C\/a\u003E","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"contributors":null,"place":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"geo":null,"user":{"follow_request_sent":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"favourites_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"dbdbdb","url":"http:\/\/www.yourwaywebsites.com\/","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795852708\/twittericon_normal.png","location":"","id_str":"129314956","notifications":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"description":"Hello, I am Brandon Vento, the founder of Your Way Websites. Our company is a small business that provides web design services to a variety of clients. ","show_all_inline_media":false,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","created_at":"Sat Apr 03 22:20:26 +0000 2010","profile_link_color":"383838","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_images\/795852708\/twittericon_normal.png","listed_count":0,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"c7c7c7","time_zone":null,"screen_name":"yourwaywebsites","profile_use_background_image":false,"statuses_count":10,"friends_count":9,"profile_background_color":"292727","protected":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"verified":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","followers_count":2,"name":"Your Way Websites","default_profile":false,"id":129314956,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","utc_offset":null,"profile_text_color":"575757"},"retweet_count":0,"coordinates":null,"truncated":false,"id":104032165674749952,"possibly_sensitive":false} [info] => Array ( [url] => https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 1563 [request_size] => 559 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.286434 [namelookup_time] => 0.123698 [connect_time] => 0.187714 [pretransfer_time] => 0.432981 [size_upload] => 20560 [size_download] => 2580 [speed_download] => 2005 [speed_upload] => 15982 [download_content_length] => 2580 [upload_content_length] => 20560 [starttransfer_time] => 0.433422 [redirect_time] => 0 [request_header] => POST /1/statuses/update_with_media.json HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: themattharris' HTTP Client Host: upload.twitter.com Accept: */* Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="nY4E8qXJVxICLYTs9R2BLQ", oauth_nonce="dfac47eb37ca8897cf2542123d1638f9", oauth_signature="lHjemKp%2BJVmVgD3cQ9ady4Qb66o%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1313638299", oauth_token="129314956-PJCTyRqrhoTr5IyLGkma9CjDbss5Uohtml2qMmll", oauth_version="1.0" Content-Length: 20560 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------258aadd70f93 ) ) )
```

Comment: can you show complete response that you got from twitter

Comment: @Adeel: My question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had to do:

```
$thing = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
$tweet_id = $thing->id_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not following object hierarchy. Use the following.

```
$tweet_id = $tmhOAuth->response->id_str;
```